# No matter what programme I write , it is showing invalid syntax. Eg. If I write a=45 print(a), it says name a is not defined?

Tags: syntax-error

a= 45
print (a)
It starts saying name "a" is not defined

What to do?
Even if I copy code from somewhere and paste then it says invalid syntax..
Even if I type in everything correct, the response is same as invalid syntax.

Comment: what language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Write it in two lines code

```py
a=45
print(a)
```

Comment: Yes I've written the code in 2 lines only

Answer (score 0):

There could be 2 simple reason for this error
First reason:
You could been writing in another file not the .py file, for example, it will give you error if you're file is a .css or .html or .js or .java etc.

Second reason:
It could be an error writing in a line for example it should be

```
a = 45
print (a)
```

Comment: Yes I wrote them in separate lines only, it was just here in comments that I wrote it together. Actually in the terminal (in bottom right) if I delete python one and choose powershell then the code runs..I do not know why this is happening, I'm from a science background..

Comment: Ok.. I think command prompt is not working, I suggest using a text editor  terminal for coding such as visual studio

Comment: Yes I use audio visual code only ..